# Create SSH user with limited privileges to only use Git repository

Tags: ssh, user-management, git

I have a git repository hosted on my SunOS server, that I remotely use through ssh

```
git clone ssh://myUser@mydomain.com/path/to/git
```

Now I need to add more users to be able to access that repository, but not sure how.

I have added one **testUser** to ssh, but I can't seem to limit that user privileges to only use git.

**testUser** is able to ssh through and browse the entire server.

How can I create users that can only access git remotely, to clone/pull/push etc...

thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might consider using [*gitolite*](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools#gitolite) under a single user instead of setting up multiple *git-shell* users (and the required group and group permissions so they can share access to the repositories).

*gitolite* runs under a single, normal user on the server and uses 
SSH public keys to differentiate access to Git repositories (see “[how gitolite uses ssh](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/glssh.html)” for some of the details of how *gitolite* does its SSH-based identification).
*gitolite* offers per-repository, per-branch, and even some per-path access control.

Comment: +1 for gitosis... It was made exactly for this setup.

Answer (score 16):

You basically have two options.

1. As topdog mentioned, when you create users on the server, set their shell to [git-shell](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-shell.html) ([book entry here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-shell)).  This will allow the user to login in via SSH, but instead of running a normal, fully-featured shell (e.g. sh,bash,etc.) it will run, git-shell, which only provides access to git functionality.
2. Alternatively, you can make your repositories available via another protocol, such as TCP (using [git-deamon](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html)) or HTTP/HTTPS.  I'd only recommend such a scenario for read-only access though.

You mention wanting to support 'push' functionality for your users, so you should really go with option #1.

Comment: note: you can change the shell of that user with `usermod -s /usr/bin/git-shell username`

Answer (score 7):

you need to change their shell to git-shell, that will only give them access to git functions only.

Comment: Thanks topdog. Basically the user will be using his own git shell on his Mac. I don't really want him to be able to ssh to the server.
So if the git repo is on mydomain.com

from testUser computer/Mac, in the terminal he could just 

git clone ssh://myUser@mydomain.com/path/to/git

be prompted for his password, then download the repo.
I just tried now setting his shell to git-shell. It prompts when calling clone but the password is being rejected.

Comment: you need to set myUsers shell to git-shell if all you want them to do on the server is run git commands and not be able to shell in. for the password prompts please use keys. For more detailed coverage of git on a server look at the free git book http://progit.org/book/ch4-0.html

Comment: thanks for the book reference! very helpful. Ended up using gitolite, still having issues with the setup though.

Comment: _git-shell_: "This is a login shell for SSH accounts to provide restricted Git access. It permits execution only of server-side Git commands implementing the pull/push functionality, plus custom commands present in a subdirectory named git-shell-commands in the user’s home directory." On Linux, add "/bin/git-shell" to "/etc/shells" and then "usermod --shell /bin/git-shell $USER". Btw, the git book is now at http://git-scm.com/book/en/ch4-0.html

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is by limit access of the users within ssh.

(http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2006/09/05/limiting-access-to-openssh-directives/)

The example is just by using only one user, but if the users are on the same group you can filter them out by using group directive. Something like

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
X11Forwarding yes

Match Group Users
         AllowTcpForwarding no
         X11Forwarding no
         $Here is a directive for git$
```

Comment: What do you mean with `$Here is a directive for git$`?